# Create wheel package installer for python project in linux to use it in various python projects

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, egg, python-wheel

I have read till not lot about how to package the python project,get to know one way is by egg and second is by wheel. Also i realized egg is superseded by wheel.
But i am not able to find exactly how i can create a wheel file out of my python project and the same can be used in various project just like pandas or numpy packages. My question is i have a python project with various python scripts it works as a framework, now i want to make installer pkg out it and would like to use same as numpy or pandas packages available. It would be great if some one can list out the steps needs to be done to convert your python project to an installer for linux envrionment ?

```
Project1
   framework
       utils.py
       readConfig.py
       main.py
       pull.py
       get.py
       store.py
   config.yaml
   ddl.sql
```

As of now i am copying the whole code to my various project and use it as a import module. but i need to use it in various project and i don't want to copy code in every project. what i am looking for your help for below points

```
 1) build a pkg name as framework.whl or framework.egg (but what are the steps required to make framework.whl out of my project ?)
 2) install framework.whl or framework.egg in linux edge node or server (it would be using pip or different way ?)
 3) use it in my other project as from framework import main as f and should be able to use various methods in main.py
```

Edit:
I don't have admin rights to perform pip as mentioned in comments. I can get it install whell, setuptool, and twine from admin team. But what i am not getting is in setup.py lot of fields needs to be filled it seems, what are the essential fields should be filled and how to fill it ?

It would be very helpful if someone can point out the step by step activities need to be done with some sample code ?

Comment: Create *setup.py* and then `pip wheel`.

Comment: how i can create setup.py and what should be code inside setup.py ?

Comment: That is well documented on both official documentation and here on StackOverflow. If you'll still have a trouble with that, ask a different question. It is not in scope of this one.

Comment: Start here: https://docs.python.org/3/distributing/index.html and then read https://packaging.python.org/